# Android Studio Kotlin Compiler warning

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I found warning in Kotlin Compiler settings

> Following modules override project settings: **app**

[image]

Project compiles and works perfect but can this warning make affect in future? And how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just go to the module settings for module `app` and in the Kotlin facet page tick the box to use "project settings".

Comment: @Strelok what, where is "Kotlin facet page tick" in the module settings?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I am not seeing a Kotlin facet page in the module settings either. (Android Studio 3.3.2)

Answer (score 3):

Open `ProjectFolder/app/app.iml` and edit the following node, changing `useProjectSettings` to true.

```
<facet type="kotlin-language" name="Kotlin">
  <configuration version="3" platform="JVM 1.6" useProjectSettings="true">
    <compilerSettings />
    <compilerArguments>
      <option name="destination" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug" />
      <option name="noStdlib" value="true" />
      <option name="noReflect" value="true" />
      <option name="moduleName" value="app_debug" />
      <option name="addCompilerBuiltIns" value="true" />
      <option name="loadBuiltInsFromDependencies" value="true" />
      <option name="languageVersion" value="1.2" />
      <option name="apiVersion" value="1.2" />
      ...
    </compilerArguments>
  </configuration>
</facet>
```

Comment: How to save this configuration? It rewrites after each rebuid.

Comment: I don't think .iml files are meant to be manually edited. By poking around Android Studio, it seems to me that Gradle wipes .iml files and regenerates them. That's why @SergeyShustikov and I are having problems modifying them. This answer is insufficient.

Comment: @XavierL. I just reinstalled Android SDK and all became works fine.