# Error: Default activity not found, but it is declared

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have strange situation that has hapenned with me twice.

I have manifest inside my main module - igs_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.example">

    <application
            android:name=".CommonApplication"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:supportsRtl="false"
            tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning, UnusedAttribute, RtlSupport">

        <activity android:name=".auth.view.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I'm trying to launch my app it looks like

[image]

And I getting an error :

[image]

I tried specify directly my default Activity, but AS said that this activity is not declared in Manifest.

[image]

#### Then I tried to `Invalidate Caches and Restart` AS and `Rebuild` the project, but it also didn't help me.

So, I waste all possible solutions. Who knows how it can be fixed?

Comment: SplashScreen is an activity??

Comment: @PembaTamang yes.

Comment: change gradle file and sync it again. It may work as the same problem  was encountered by me.

Comment: @primo didn't worked as well

Comment: I think in your activity package="com.example". And you have blurred out the Splashactivity package. Change it to correct package name I think.

Comment: @MonsterBrain I changed it due to NDA

Comment: Please check if your manifest is still using that package name ... com.example

Comment: See what happens in your merged manifest file, maybe for some weird reason the activity is not included there (although I cannot see how that might happen).

Comment: @azizbekian I unzip apk and found my SplashScreen in AndroidManifest, with normal action and category. More than : I am able to install my apk and launch on device. No crashes.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov: Have you renamed the package identifier of project then seen this error?

Comment: @aminography no, I edited this package only when was creating stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why it can be linked to this problem, but the reason of this problem comes from Kotlin Compiler. When I launched Kotlin compiler options I saw warning and after few seconds of googling I found an answer which described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912853/4969827.

After changing `useProjectSettings` to `true` all became work properly!

To prevent information loss I copy-paste original snippet to here.

```
<facet type="kotlin-language" name="Kotlin">
  <configuration version="3" platform="JVM 1.6" useProjectSettings="true">
    <compilerSettings />
    <compilerArguments>
      <option name="destination" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug" />
      <option name="noStdlib" value="true" />
      <option name="noReflect" value="true" />
      <option name="moduleName" value="app_debug" />
      <option name="addCompilerBuiltIns" value="true" />
      <option name="loadBuiltInsFromDependencies" value="true" />
      <option name="languageVersion" value="1.2" />
      <option name="apiVersion" value="1.2" />
      ...
    </compilerArguments>
  </configuration>
</facet>
```

## YOU MUST READ TEXT BELOW

**However problems continue came up. More seldom, but came. Some day I was editing xml files and I found broken APPT. So the problem was in SDK, which I deleted and installed again. After this all works fine.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your question you clearly mentioned that *"I have manifest inside **main** module"* but you're using `igs_main` like this:

[image]

You need to change it to `app` module like below

[image]

And then try to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when your Activity class is not public but default (when you don't specify any access modifiers), have a look that it is `public class SplashScreen`? 
If you don't make all activity class as public if you don't then on some devices it might crash.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me when I changed in manifest `allowBackup` from `true` to `false` `android:allowBackup="false"` , then I googled I found this answer, and I see that he also had allowBackup defined to `false`. Now when I change back to `true` everything is in normal. Looks wired, I don't have clear explanation.