# unable to detect default activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Please read it Since I couldn't find any solution

I was working on Android studio, accidentally i found that an X flag at app play button

and when i try to run the application i need to edit the configuration >>General tab>> Launch option to Nothing. and when i'm trying to set it to default activity it says that Warning: Default Activity not found
however i have double checked my manifest and i don't believe there is a problem and also the application is working properly but im unable to debug it . 
please find bellow my manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.finalfax.businesshub">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".core.helper.app.Config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignInActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MenuActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContainerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.OtpActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddPostActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name="com.tuenti.smsradar.SmsRadarService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ViewPhotosPopUpActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MyProfileActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.AboutUsActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did u try to invalidate and restart

Comment: yes two or three times

Comment: your code in kotlin??

Comment: @ALTegani No it's java

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790881/error-default-activity-not-found-but-it-is-declared

Comment: its not caching its working perfect but not in debug mode, however i tried this solution and it didn't work

Comment: Did you try setting Launch option to specified activity and then passing fully qualified name of your Launcher activity to see if it works! This will check if the problem is with your activity or android studio.

Comment: Yes i tried that also, it doesn't work
it still say that not in manifest

Comment: Then I guess the problem is with HomeActivity. Is it public?

Comment: Sure it never be as protected or private i already checked it

Comment: i think its from the sdk itself delete and reinstall

Comment: so should i re install android studio with sdk ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in android studio since it is not working even when passing the fully qualified path in launch option.

Comment: android studio installing the application perfect and i can see the changes 
but it's not opening the  app automatically

Comment: yes i think just sdk

Comment: i have reinstalled android studio with new SDK it works now

Comment: glad for you @BasilBattikhi

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened with me on Android Studio 3.2.1. Try The following :

1. In Android Studio open your project and click "File" - Close project and don't close Android Studio Window.
2. Go to your project directory and delete .idea Directory.
3. Get back to Android Studio Window and click on your project Shortcut like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbPIJ.png) .

I hope that this solved your problem.

Comment: i have reinstalled android studio with new SDK it works now, thanks for your answer